# How to fix animation lowering my header height?

Tags: html, css

The animation lowers the height of the h1 and then once the animation is completed, it snaps back into position.

```css
       .main-header {
            position: absolute;
            top: 40%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        
            animation-name: moveInLeft;
            animation-duration: 1s;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        }
        
        .wrap {
            background-color: gray;
            height: 90vh;
        }
        
        
        
        @keyframes moveInLeft {
            0% {
                opacity: 0;
                transform: translateX(-100px);
            }
        
            80% {
                transform: translateX(10px);
            }
        
            100% {
                opacity: 1;
                transform: translate(0);
            }
        }
```

```html
      
  <header class="wrap">  
      <h1 class="main-header">
          This is a header
      </h1>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid not checking the whole code before posting it here.

```css
    * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  border: white solid 1px;
}

.header-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
}

.main-nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

h1.main-header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transition: left, top;
  animation-name: moveInLeft;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.wrap {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 90vh;
}

@keyframes moveInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100px);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateX(150px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
    
<header class="wrap">  
    <nav class="header-container">
        
        <h2 class="header-text">
            <a href="#">Text</a>
        </h2>
            
        <ul class="main-nav"> 
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        
    </nav>

    <h1 class="main-header">
        This is a header
    </h1>
</header>  

</body>
</html>
```

This should work as expected. Note the different use of `transform: translate;` and `transition: left, top;`, since `transform: translate;` is used to move the object for defined value(here 50% both X and Y) and you haven't set the returning position to match starting point, thus I've made it simple and used `transition: left, top;` and changed only value of X to move right then return left.

Comment: My issue is that the header is lower when the animation starts, and then returns to the intended height once the animation ends

Comment: Now the issue with header ending on a different height is resolved.

Comment: And how is that not what you're after?

Comment: You've lowered the header and it's no longer center

Comment: This is not a code writing service, I've resolved your problem, now you can change to meet your standards. If you don't know how to do that, please change question or post another one.

Comment: And even tho it's not a code writing service, I've fixed the code so it meets your standards.

Comment: I used transform: translate(-50%, -50%); so the header was centered. Thanks anyway

Comment: That wasn't for the header to be centered, you center it with **top** and **left** which were set to 50% and 40%, but I've changed it to 50% 50%. That is why your animation had a height problems and initially translate is not used for that, unless you make a animation for returning from left to right(e.g. center)

Comment: Also see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cevrozsL/) a working fiddle, so you can make changes on go.

Comment: Then either delete the question or post your answer.

Answer (score 0):

this happening because of `translate(-50% ,-50%)` wich is replaced by `aniamtion` transform.

if you want to center your `header` you can use `flex` display on the `header` parent like this:

```css
.main-header {
        animation-name: moveInLeft;
        animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-repeat:infinite;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    
    .wrap {
        background-color: gray;
        height: 90vh;
      display:flex;
      align-items:center;
      justify-content:space-around
    }
    
    
    
    @keyframes moveInLeft {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translateX(-100px);
        }
    
        80% {
            transform: translateX(10px);
        }
    
        100% {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translate(0);
        }
    }

  <header class="wrap">  
        <h1 class="main-header">
            This is a header
        </h1>
    </header>  

    .main-header {
        position: absolute;
        top: 40%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    
        animation-name: moveInLeft;
        animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    
    .wrap {
        background-color: gray;
        height: 90vh;
    }
    
    
    
    @keyframes moveInLeft {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translateX(-100px);
        }
    
        80% {
            transform: translateX(10px);
        }
    
        100% {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translate(0);
        }
    }
```

```html
  <header class="wrap">  
        <h1 class="main-header">
            This is a header
        </h1>
    </header>
```

because you have specific `height:90vh` on your `.wrap` parent you can use `align-items:center` for vertical align the header and `justify-content` work for horizontal `align`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `animation-fill-mode:forwards;` check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) for the property details.

```css
       .main-header {
            position: absolute;
            top: 40%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        
            animation-name: moveInLeft;
            animation-duration: 1s;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-fill-mode:forwards;
        }
        
        .wrap {
            background-color: gray;
            height: 90vh;
        }
        
        
        
        @keyframes moveInLeft {
            0% {
                opacity: 0;
                transform: translateX(-100px);
            }
        
            80% {
                transform: translateX(10px);
            }
        
            100% {
                opacity: 1;
                transform: translate(0);
            }
        }
```

```html
      
  <header class="wrap">  
      <h1 class="main-header">
          This is a header
      </h1>
  </header>
```